# Is there a way to decrypt a String that is hashed into a CRC int from a specific table?

Tags: java, string, bit-manipulation, crc

I have this very archaic Java code that has left behind a one-way solution for converting strings (which are always "some_string_like_this_03" format) into a CRC using bitwise math that is referenced by a lot of other mechanics in the very large codebase.

Is there any reasonable way to reverse this so I can add a `getStringFromCrc` method?

```java
public static int getStringCrc(String s)
{
    int crc = CRC_INIT;
    if (s != null)
    {
        char[] c = s.toCharArray();
        for (char c1 : c) crc = crctable[((crc >> 24) ^ (c1 & 0xff)) & 0xff] ^ (crc << 8);
    }
    return crc ^ CRC_INIT;
}
```

```java
public final static int CRC_INIT = 0xFFFFFFFF;
public final static int[] crctable =
{
    0x00000000, 0x04C11DB7, 0x09823B6E, 0x0D4326D9, 0x130476DC, 0x17C56B6B, 0x1A864DB2, 0x1E475005,
    0x2608EDB8, 0x22C9F00F, 0x2F8AD6D6, 0x2B4BCB61, 0x350C9B64, 0x31CD86D3, 0x3C8EA00A, 0x384FBDBD,
    0x4C11DB70, 0x48D0C6C7, 0x4593E01E, 0x4152FDA9, 0x5F15ADAC, 0x5BD4B01B, 0x569796C2, 0x52568B75,
    0x6A1936C8, 0x6ED82B7F, 0x639B0DA6, 0x675A1011, 0x791D4014, 0x7DDC5DA3, 0x709F7B7A, 0x745E66CD,
    0x9823B6E0, 0x9CE2AB57, 0x91A18D8E, 0x95609039, 0x8B27C03C, 0x8FE6DD8B, 0x82A5FB52, 0x8664E6E5,
    0xBE2B5B58, 0xBAEA46EF, 0xB7A96036, 0xB3687D81, 0xAD2F2D84, 0xA9EE3033, 0xA4AD16EA, 0xA06C0B5D,
    0xD4326D90, 0xD0F37027, 0xDDB056FE, 0xD9714B49, 0xC7361B4C, 0xC3F706FB, 0xCEB42022, 0xCA753D95,
    0xF23A8028, 0xF6FB9D9F, 0xFBB8BB46, 0xFF79A6F1, 0xE13EF6F4, 0xE5FFEB43, 0xE8BCCD9A, 0xEC7DD02D,
    0x34867077, 0x30476DC0, 0x3D044B19, 0x39C556AE, 0x278206AB, 0x23431B1C, 0x2E003DC5, 0x2AC12072,
    0x128E9DCF, 0x164F8078, 0x1B0CA6A1, 0x1FCDBB16, 0x018AEB13, 0x054BF6A4, 0x0808D07D, 0x0CC9CDCA,
    0x7897AB07, 0x7C56B6B0, 0x71159069, 0x75D48DDE, 0x6B93DDDB, 0x6F52C06C, 0x6211E6B5, 0x66D0FB02,
    0x5E9F46BF, 0x5A5E5B08, 0x571D7DD1, 0x53DC6066, 0x4D9B3063, 0x495A2DD4, 0x44190B0D, 0x40D816BA,
    0xACA5C697, 0xA864DB20, 0xA527FDF9, 0xA1E6E04E, 0xBFA1B04B, 0xBB60ADFC, 0xB6238B25, 0xB2E29692,
    0x8AAD2B2F, 0x8E6C3698, 0x832F1041, 0x87EE0DF6, 0x99A95DF3, 0x9D684044, 0x902B669D, 0x94EA7B2A,
    0xE0B41DE7, 0xE4750050, 0xE9362689, 0xEDF73B3E, 0xF3B06B3B, 0xF771768C, 0xFA325055, 0xFEF34DE2,
    0xC6BCF05F, 0xC27DEDE8, 0xCF3ECB31, 0xCBFFD686, 0xD5B88683, 0xD1799B34, 0xDC3ABDED, 0xD8FBA05A,
    0x690CE0EE, 0x6DCDFD59, 0x608EDB80, 0x644FC637, 0x7A089632, 0x7EC98B85, 0x738AAD5C, 0x774BB0EB,
    0x4F040D56, 0x4BC510E1, 0x46863638, 0x42472B8F, 0x5C007B8A, 0x58C1663D, 0x558240E4, 0x51435D53,
    0x251D3B9E, 0x21DC2629, 0x2C9F00F0, 0x285E1D47, 0x36194D42, 0x32D850F5, 0x3F9B762C, 0x3B5A6B9B,
    0x0315D626, 0x07D4CB91, 0x0A97ED48, 0x0E56F0FF, 0x1011A0FA, 0x14D0BD4D, 0x19939B94, 0x1D528623,
    0xF12F560E, 0xF5EE4BB9, 0xF8AD6D60, 0xFC6C70D7, 0xE22B20D2, 0xE6EA3D65, 0xEBA91BBC, 0xEF68060B,
    0xD727BBB6, 0xD3E6A601, 0xDEA580D8, 0xDA649D6F, 0xC423CD6A, 0xC0E2D0DD, 0xCDA1F604, 0xC960EBB3,
    0xBD3E8D7E, 0xB9FF90C9, 0xB4BCB610, 0xB07DABA7, 0xAE3AFBA2, 0xAAFBE615, 0xA7B8C0CC, 0xA379DD7B,
    0x9B3660C6, 0x9FF77D71, 0x92B45BA8, 0x9675461F, 0x8832161A, 0x8CF30BAD, 0x81B02D74, 0x857130C3,
    0x5D8A9099, 0x594B8D2E, 0x5408ABF7, 0x50C9B640, 0x4E8EE645, 0x4A4FFBF2, 0x470CDD2B, 0x43CDC09C,
    0x7B827D21, 0x7F436096, 0x7200464F, 0x76C15BF8, 0x68860BFD, 0x6C47164A, 0x61043093, 0x65C52D24,
    0x119B4BE9, 0x155A565E, 0x18197087, 0x1CD86D30, 0x029F3D35, 0x065E2082, 0x0B1D065B, 0x0FDC1BEC,
    0x3793A651, 0x3352BBE6, 0x3E119D3F, 0x3AD08088, 0x2497D08D, 0x2056CD3A, 0x2D15EBE3, 0x29D4F654,
    0xC5A92679, 0xC1683BCE, 0xCC2B1D17, 0xC8EA00A0, 0xD6AD50A5, 0xD26C4D12, 0xDF2F6BCB, 0xDBEE767C,
    0xE3A1CBC1, 0xE760D676, 0xEA23F0AF, 0xEEE2ED18, 0xF0A5BD1D, 0xF464A0AA, 0xF9278673, 0xFDE69BC4,
    0x89B8FD09, 0x8D79E0BE, 0x803AC667, 0x84FBDBD0, 0x9ABC8BD5, 0x9E7D9662, 0x933EB0BB, 0x97FFAD0C,
    0xAFB010B1, 0xAB710D06, 0xA6322BDF, 0xA2F33668, 0xBCB4666D, 0xB8757BDA, 0xB5365D03, 0xB1F740B4
};
```

Comment: If 4 or less characters are the only variables, and always in the same place in a string, then it would be possible to recreate the string from a 32 bit CRC.

Comment: If you know the prefix and only the last 2 to 4 characters are a mystery then this should be doable. You could even to a brute force approach without understanding the CRC logic.

Comment: Fortunately this looks good, though there could be more than one solution, or a password too long. As one has to collect several candidates for every additional letter. Interesting puzzle. Mind that you have 256 candidate CRCs. So I would need to actually check it. and time things

Comment: Is the set of input-strings finite and/or fixed? If it is fixed with a relatively low ordinality, you might be able to build a lookup table (if there are no collisions).

Comment: @JoachimSauer The strings aren't passwords and only contain a-z A-Z 0-9 and underscores (e.g. one might be like "handle_system_process_04").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the input strings are as you describe, then it is NOT POSSIBLE to reverse a CRC to recover the original string.

If we consider (just) 24 character strings comprising lowercase letters, digits and underscores (as per your example), there are 37<sup>24</sup> possible strings.  That is approximately 4.3335257 * 10<sup>37</sup>.

But if we generate a CRC the will fit into an `int`, there are only 2<sup>32</sup> CRC values possible.  That is 4294967296 or 4.294967296 * 10<sup>10</sup>.

If we divide the former by the latter we get the result that each CRC value matches 1.0089776 * 10<sup>28</sup> possible 24 character strings.  But there is no way of knowing which of the possible strings is the correct one.

---

The only case where the CRC might be reversible for strings of this size is if:

1. the set of actual strings is relatively small, AND
2. you know what all of the strings are beforehand, AND
3. there aren't any CRC collisions; i.e. no two strings have the same CRC.

In that case you could calculate the CRCs for all of the strings, and then populate a `Map<Integer, String>` with entries for each CRC and the string it was generated from.

But I don't think this matches the problem that you have described ... so I think this is a non-solution.

Answer (score 3):

I think you mean a `getStringFromCrc` method.

Unless you happen to know that the string contains 32 bits of information or less, and that the strings have a one-to-one mapping to the CRCs, then no, it's not possible. See the [pigeon hole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).

If those criteria are met, then you *can* find the original string. E.g. if the string has four characters or less.